# ODBC connection from a Linux box to MS SQLServer

Tags: linux, fedora, sqlserver, odbc

I need to connect to MS SQLServer from a Linux box using ODBC from a Qt application I am developing.

So far I have installed the ODBC MS SQLServer driver and Kerberos on the Linux box.  Using kinit I am able to get a ticket for my windows user (mvincent@mydomain.local).

I am logged into the Linux box as a local user (mvincent@linuxbox).

I am unsure how to get a ticket from windows active directory for my linux box login as mvincent@linuxbox is not in Active Directory.

I am using `Trusted_Connection=yes` in my ODBC connection string. The MS SQLServer instance is configured to only use Windows authentication so I can't use `Uid=xxx` and `Pwd=ssss` in the connection string.

How can I connect to MS SQLServer in the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

At the time you asked, it wasn't supported.

Now, you will need at least 17.6 of the driver (17.9 is current)

MS instructions at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15

At the very least you should add to your DSN:
Trusted_Connection=yes

The kerberos tokens need to have been obtained prior to attempting the connection, using either kinit or via pam.

The following line suggests that you might have to have actually logged into the server via kerberos:

*Ensure that the login to the system was done using the Kerberos PAM (Pluggable Authentication Module)*

And you need to renew the credentials before they expire, since the odbc driver doesn't do that for you.